# Use lxml find element to parse Arxiv XML from API

Tags: python, lxml

I'm fetching xml from Arxiv and I want to parse all Arxiv entries after reading it using `lxml` library. Here is my code to grab XML file of 100 of articles.

```
import urllib
from lxml import etree

start_index = 0
results_per_iteration = 100
base_url = 'http://export.arxiv.org/api/query?'
search_query = 'cat:cs.CV+OR+cat:cs.LG+OR+cat:cs.CL+OR+cat:cs.NE+OR+cat:stat.ML'
query = 'search_query=%s&sortBy=lastUpdatedDate&start=%i&max_results=%i'\
    % (search_query, start_index, start_index + results_per_iteration)

response = urllib.request.urlopen(base_url + query).read() # python 3.x
# response = urllib.urlopen(base_url + query).read() # python 2.x
tree = etree.fromstring(response)
```

Now, I have to do as following to find all entries from the xml.

```
e_ = tree.findall('{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}entry')
```

And in order to find `id`, I have to do the following

```
print(e_.find('{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}id').text)
```

**Question** is I want to know if there is a way to parse this XML where we don't have to provide `{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}` when finding elements i.e. `tree.findall('entry')` or `lxml` script that has some functionality that works similar to [feedparser](https://github.com/kurtmckee/feedparser).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following XPath expression to match element by its *local-name*, ignoring the namespace :

```
e_ = tree.xpath('*[local-name()="entry"]')
```

Comment: Thanks har07! I didn't know this trick before. This works perfect.